# What does the 'x' mean in rwx on a directory?

Tags: linux, security, unix

I got a testdir by `mkdir testdir`, and created a file in it by `touch testdir/a`.

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 jermaine     jermaine       4096 Mar 12 22:57 testdir
```

If I remove the 'x' by `chmod -x testdir`

Then I won't be able to

```
cd testdir

touch testdir/b

ls -l testdir

cat testdir/a
```

So my question is why can't I list the file hierarchy under a directory with a 'r' but without an 'x'? What exactly does the 'x' mean on directory?

I knew some explanations like "x means entering the direcotry, you have to enter before read and write". But what does 'enter' mean? I really appreciate answers on inode or dentry level. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On Unix directories have to have the executable flag in order to be browseable.

Comment: Incorrect, to list a directory, you will need both r and x

Comment: Observe that you will need x on a directory as well as every every parent directory to make it accessable.

Comment: @AndersLindén: Incorrect, to list a directory you need only `r`. But, you will not be able to get any information about the files within that directory without `x` (i.e. you will get only a bare list of names).

Comment: nneonneo: Show me an example on how that can be

Comment: @AndersLindén: `chmod 444` on a non-empty directory and try to list it with `ls -la`. You will get a bunch of permission denied errors and a listing that shows the filenames, but everything else (permissions, sizes, dates, etc.) will be question marks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Execute" is the *traversal* permission on a directory. It allows you to access files and folders within the directory.

If you can *read* a directory, you can list the contents.

If you can *write* a directory, you can make new files and folders within it.

If you can "*execute*" a directory, you can move through the hierarchy, even if you don't know what's inside.

Answer (score 15):

When applying permissions to directories on Linux, the permission bits have different meanings than on regular files.

- The write bit allows the affected user to create, rename, or delete files within the directory, and modify the directory's attributes
- The read bit allows the affected user to list the files within the directory
- The execute bit allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside

Comment: +1, finally someone who understands.

Answer (score -1):

Execute permission on a directory means you can access files in that directory.

Check this link out for more information about Unix permissions:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-linux-file-permissions-work/

Comment: This is factually incorrect. `r` permission lets you list files.

Comment: nneonneo: You're right, thanks for the comment, I got a bit confused =)